# How should the Dispatch Bot parent app update along side the children LUIS applications and why can't the dispatch app be the main app

Tags: botframework, chatbot, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

So from what I am seeing is that when you create the dispatch luis application through the cli you get an app which has all of the intents from all of the children apps including anything from the qna maker. Meaning the intents and entities associated could be potentially in the thousands.

This serves to act as a gateway for the other luis children apps and qna maker apps.

What is the advisable update pattern for updating the LUIS dispatch app when other children apps have been updated throughout the services?

Meaning, if I update my child LUIS apps and train and publish them don't I have to immediately update the dispatch app through the cli again?  Is there version control for this and or is the parent app versioned or is another created?

Is there a way to update everything together or does it have to be separately through the dispatch cli?

What does this mean for the luis application api such as for a container?  Would the api even work for that?  Or would the update to the container have to be a manual file export and import into the container?

Lastly bonus question from thinking about all of this.

Why can't the dispatch app just be the single source of truth and updating any children would auto update the parent and code base would just call and reference the one major / parent luis app?

Answer (score 1):

Trying to answer your questions(quite a few!!) in an order:

- Meaning, if I update my child LUIS apps and train and publish them don't I have to immediately update the dispatch app through the cli again?

  A: Yes, you will have to immediately update the dispatch app through the CLI again if you update the child LUIS apps and train and publish them.
- Is there version control for this and or is the parent app versioned or is another created?

  A: The parent app is updated but no new app is created.
- Is there a way to update everything together or does it have to be separately through the dispatch cli?

  A: There is no way to update everything together. You would have to update separately through the CLI. People generally set up scripts which runs “dispatch refresh” daily in their dev ops pipeline to pick up any changes in the underlying LUIS/QnA models.
- What does this mean for the luis application api such as for a container? Would the api even work for that? Or would the update to the container have to be a manual file export and import into the container?

  A: Not sure if I understand your question correctly,but while running Dispatch in container, one would have to manually export and import it into the container.  Ideally, script which runs “dispatch refresh” should also automate the export (could be done via API)/import into container.
- Why can't the dispatch app just be the single source of truth and updating any children would auto update the parent and code base would just call and reference the one major / parent luis app?

  A: Finally, some good news!! The LUIS team is working on a feature to achieve this, not sure when it would be made available.

Hope this helps.